# Given a lines parametric equations, and a point how do I find the closest point on that line to that point.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I thought of using the dot product set to $0$ but I'd need two vectors, and I only have one if I use the parametric equations as $x, y, z$ values of a vector.

This is the example:

Line: $l = [(t,14-t,t-5)]$

Point: $A(1,3,4)$

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimize using the distance formula. The distance of a point on the line to A at time $t$ is $$d(t)=\sqrt{(1-t)^2+(3-(14-t))^2+(4-(t-5))^2}.$$ Then differentiate to find the minimum. Note: one can minimize the distance squared.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a dot product was good. The two vectors that you need for this are the vector from $A$ to a point on the line and the vector from some other arbitrary point on the line to that one. A convenient choice is to set $t=0$, so you end up having to solve $$
(l(t)-[1,3,4])\cdot(l(t)-l(0)) = [t-1,11-t,t-9]\cdot[t,-t,t] = 3t^2-21t = 0.
$$ This has two solutions, but you can discard $0$ since that corresponds to the zero vector, which is orthogonal to everything. The other solution happily agrees with the one you get by [minimizing the distance function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609688/265466) as suggested by Brad A.M..

Comment: Instead of setting t = 0 could I not just use the coefficients from of t in that line equations, I seem to think those would represent the directional vector of the line, please correct me if im incorrect.

Comment: @TeyashArjun Yes! That also has the benefit of eliminating the extraneous $0$ solution. You end up with a linear equation for $t$.